# Can we read ios storyboard xml code?

Tags: ios

Hi i want to read ios app storyboard xml file and wants to store it in array or any other place. So is it possible to read storyboard xml file.

Comment: You must try it out first! for example, have you tried using `let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource()`? if you are unsuccessful, share you tried and we can help you fix.

Comment: hii i tried it gives null as a path here is the code  NSString *path= [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Main" ofType:@"storyboard"];

Comment: Also tried this NSString *path= [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Main" ofType:@"storyboardc"]; using this i got a path. But now how to read storyboard xml code??

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Just right click on **storyboard** file and **select open as source code**. That's it.

Comment: Read mean i want to fetch xml data.

Answer (score 0):

open the project navigator on the left, select the Main.storyboard, right click, select open as "source code"

Comment: Read mean i want to fetch xml data.